# Div will not float left when window is be being resized

Tags: html, css

hello I Know some people have problems with this, and has asked about it before, but I tried every answer and it doesn't work.

**My problem**
I have a div that has a css command of **float** **right**. The panel is in the right side but for some reason when the window resizes to a  certain size the div moves down.

**How do I fix this.**

**Code.**

```
<p:panel class="MembersPanel" >
        <f:facet name="header">
            <p>
           Psst Members over here!
            </p>
        </f:facet>
    </p:panel>
```

**Code .css**

```
.MembersPanel{

    float:right;  

    padding-left:3px; margin-right: 10px;
    height:450px; 
    width:22%; 
    margin-top: 10px; 


    border-radius: 4px;
}
```

**Picture examples.**

***Example: 1***

This is the panel at its regular size. (The window is 100%);

[image: Window: 1]

***Example: 2***

The windows side is being reduced. Notice that the panel on the right is reducing too. I want that.

[image: Picture 2:]

***Example: 3***

This is where my problem is.
When the window reduces to a certain size the right panel moves down for some reason. 
[image: Picture 3:]

**Conclusion**

That concludes my question. If you have any question don't hesitate to ask me.

**Also**

I am looking for java ee back-end developers. LOL this website is going to need it! I am hiring.
Thanks.

**Experiment Variable**

***Whole css code.***

```
.SlideShowBackground{
    height: 600px;
    width: 100%;
    border:none;
    border-radius: 0;

}
.SlideShowSwitch{
    width: 100%;
    height: 600px;
    border: 0;
    background-image: url("http://assets.coolhunting.com/coolhunting/2015/10/12/large_hoverboard-3.jpg");
    background-size: cover;
}
/*File: VOLhome*/

.center_content{
    width: 100%;
    height:auto;
    display:block;
    overflow: auto;
}

/*File: HOmeVoolvern*/




.InsideleftPanelHoldsProj{
    float:left;
    border:none;
    margin-left: 20px;
    width: 70%;

    margin-left: 70px;
      display:block;
    overflow: auto;

}
.InsideleftPanelHoldsProj .ui-panel{
    float:left;
    height:350px;
    width:32%;
    margin-left: 3px;
    margin-top: 15px;
    border-radius: 0;
position: relative;

}

.**MembersPanel{
    float:right;  

    height:450px; 
    width:22%; 
    margin-top: 20px; 
  padding-left:1%;
margin-right:1%;
border-right:none;
border-left:none;

}**
```

***HTML code.***

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8' ?>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"
      xmlns:ui="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/facelets"
      xmlns:p="http://primefaces.org/ui"
      xmlns:f="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/core"
      xmlns:h="http://xmlns.jcp.org/jsf/html">
    <h:head>

    </h:head>
    <h:body>


    <p:panel class="SlideShowBackground">
                    <p:imageSwitch class="SlideShowSwitch" effect="turnDown">
    
</p:imageSwitch>
 
                </p:panel>

                <p:panel class="InsideleftPanelHoldsProj" >
                    <ui:include src="./ProjectsELements.xhtml"/>
                    <f:facet name="footer">
                        <ui:include src="./footer.xhtml"/>
                    </f:facet>
                </p:panel>

        <p:panel class="MembersPanel" >
            <f:facet name="header">
                <p>
               Psst Members over here!
                </p>
            </f:facet>
        </p:panel>




    </h:body>
</html>
```

Comment: I do not see any problem. What you describe is the expected behavior of _float_ property, isn´t it?

Comment: @irieill correct. At least that's what I think.

Answer (score 0):

If you use % for the width of the divs try to use it for the padding and margin to.

**Your new Code**

```
.MembersPanel{

float:right;  

padding-left:[number]%;
margin-right:[number]%;
height:450px; 
width:22%; 
margin-top: 10px; 


border-radius: 4px;
}
```

Comment: Didn't work panel still moved down. I had to set the left and right margins to 1% because if set it to any greater it would move down automatically because apparently float divs can not overlap each other.  Thanks for the try though.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't post the complete code, but, I would say: Move that panel in the HTML, put it *in front of*  those other boxes that are at the same height on larger screens. Then t should stay on top in that section and the other boxes should float left and below it.

EDIT after added code: Inside the body, try to use your HTML in the following order:

```
 <p:panel class="SlideShowBackground">
   <p:imageSwitch class="SlideShowSwitch" effect="turnDown">
    </p:imageSwitch>
 </p:panel>

 <p:panel class="MembersPanel" >
   <f:facet name="header">
     <p>
       Psst Members over here!
     </p>
   </f:facet>
  </p:panel>

  <p:panel class="InsideleftPanelHoldsProj" >
     <ui:include src="./ProjectsELements.xhtml"/>
     <f:facet name="footer">
        <ui:include src="./footer.xhtml"/>
      </f:facet>
  </p:panel>
```

Comment: hu? Sorry I don't understand.

Comment: Well, you didn't post your relevant code (the other HTML and CSS, just the code of the panel itself, which doesn't tell anything about it in relation to the rest of the code), so I can't do much more than give you a more general answer that describes what i think are the necessary steps to fix your problem.

Comment: Sorry I thought that was enough info to work with. I have worked with less. I will post my the rest of the code.